# How to track individual links in email newsletter through Mandrill (or an alternative)?

Tags: email, tracking, mandrill

I'm sending regular newsletters through Mailpoet running on a WP site, integrated with Mandrill's API.

In said newsletters I've got multiple links to posts on my blog plus excerpts of the posts. I'm currently tracking all links through Mandrill and a sum of all link clicks shows up at my Mandrill Url Tracking screen. Problem is, for the newsletters I'm sending out, it's essential to see which **specific** links are getting the most attention (clicks), so I've got an idea what content is relevant to readers.

I've searched all over google and stackoverflow but I haven't found an answer. If there's a way to track specific link activity using Mandrill or any other transactional mail service, or *any other conceivable method* of tracking individual links in an email being clicked, that'd be fine - this functionality is critical for my project at this point.

I'm a bit over my head here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mandrill search and info APIs return the following information:

```
  "clicks_detail": [
        {
            "ts": 1365190001,
            "url": "http://www.example.com",
            "ip": "55.55.55.55",
            "location": "Georgia, US",
            "ua": "Linux/Ubuntu/Chrome/Chrome 28.0.1500.53"
        }
```

You can use a Mandrill java library to parse this data, and put it into 
excel/sql and group by url and count(*) will give which URLs are most clicked.

url field in the above response, is an url in the email . it shows when/where that URL was clicked.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

Mandrill tracks emails on an per-recipient basis rather than grouping stats together in a discreet bulk send or newsletter report by default. But there are a couple of things you can do to see clicks on individual links easily.

You can search your outbound activity in the Mandrill web interface or API (messages/search) based on URL. For example: `url:"https://yourdomain.com/someotherpage/` or `url:"https://yourdomain.com/somepattern*` That will still show you clicks for an individual recipient though, so if you need to group 'emails' together, you might want to set up tags or custom message metadata so you can group stats together that way. For example, you might use a tag for your bulk email called 'newsletter.' Then, after that email sends, you can search your outbound activity by that tag and then see which recipients clicked on which URLs, and optionally export that data as well.

You could also set up webhooks to get information about clicks on specific URLs as they happen and then aggregate that data in your own app as needed.

Comment: Much obliged for the answer! Learned loads about mandrill. Sorry for the delay in responding